# Callout View doesn't close

Tags: xcode, xib, callouts

I tap to an annotation pin the callout view shows but while I select annotation pin the previous View doesn't close.

View Controller

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    // 1
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation
    {
        // Don't proceed with custom callout
        return
    }
    // 2
    let pimAnnotation = view.annotation as! AnnotationPin
    let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CalloutView", owner: nil, options: nil)
    let calloutView = views?[0] as! CalloutViewController
    calloutView.titleXib.text = pimAnnotation.title
    calloutView.subtitleXib.text = pimAnnotation.subtitle
    calloutView.imageXib.image = pimAnnotation.image
    // 3
    calloutView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width / 2, y: -calloutView.bounds.size.height*0.52)
    view.addSubview(calloutView)
    mapView.setCenter((view.annotation?.coordinate)!, animated: true)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view.isKind(of: CalloutAnnotationView.self)
    {
        for subview in view.subviews
        {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukUN8.png)

what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You don't add callout view with `view.addSubview(calloutView)` inside `mapView(mapView:didSelect view:)`, that sound like a bad practice. You should use `mapView(mapView:viewFor annotation:)` for that.

You are also trying to remove the subviews of the annotationView, not itself.

Example for using `mapView(mapView:viewFor annotation:)`:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation is StoreAnnotation else { return nil }
        
        var annotationView: MapAnnotationView?
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "annotationView", for: annotation) as? MapAnnotationView
        } else {
            annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "annotationView") as? MapAnnotationView
            if annotationView == nil {
                annotationView = MapAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotationView")
            }
        }
        
        //configure annotation view...
        
        annotationView?.delegate = self
        
        return annotationView
    }
```